# Change size of element on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to recalculate the height of elements on window resize. The code successfully calculates the necessary heights when the page loads, but not when the window is resized.

The aim is to adjust the size of the box to accommodate a text string that breaks into two or three lines when the window is shrunk down.

```js
function frontNewsResize() {
  var highestBox = 0;
  jQuery('.front-news-wrapper .front-news-article .article-title-container').each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).height() > highestBox) {
      highestBox = jQuery(this).height();
    }
  });
  jQuery('.front-news-wrapper .front-news-article .article-title-container').height(highestBox);
}

jQuery(document).ready(frontNewsResize);
jQuery(window).on('resize', frontNewsResize);
```

Comment: Use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to do this, not Javascript.

Comment: @Liam I would just use CSS if the heights were consistent, but in this case I don't know what the height of the tallest element will be. Do you know of a way to handle that with just CSS?

Comment: Issue when you set the height, and cause the item to shrink, won;t the height always be bigger?

Comment: You can almost certainly do that with [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex). Modern CSS has a lot of options to handle these situations now. You should rarely need to reach for JS to solve layout issues. If you do 90% of the time your layout is wrong. Also see the [Bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) for an "off the shelf" solution